# My cmd tries to use a user folder that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I am trying to upgrade node.js but when using the command nvm uses a USERNAME that is not registered on my computer and not the USERNAME I have always used. [This is the error message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WArcz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
type in cmd prompt
nvm -v
If it doesnt return error it means it is installed. There must be some other issue. If error returns same as nvm doesnt exist on device. Move to step 2.

Step 2:
U need to download the zip package of nvm for windows on ur device manually and then install it.

Step 3:
Once it is installed. Try step 1 again.

Step4:
Now u ready to install any version of node on ur device.
nvm 12

Further details can be found on link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows

Comment: My bad, I should have mentioned that nvm -v works and that the problem doesn't come from there. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you kindly share what does
nvm ls
returns. If it returns no installation found it means
once you find the exact version numbers that have been installed on your device for nvm then you can try:
nvm [version no]
This is how you can easily use the command.

For further description, try the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows